# How to best analyze timeseries data as predictors of a single point data? in python

Tags: python, time-series, regression

I have timeseries data of mean daily soil moisture values and daily soil temperature values and I want to see if they have a significant effect on the yield from the final harvest (which is not timeseries data just the single harvest data). What is the best method to analyze this? I read that ANOVA shouldn't be used for timeseries data because it doesn't follow the assumption of independence.

Here is an example of the dataset:

```
            mean_wcm3  mean_stemp  yield_Mg_ha sample_id
date                                          
2022-03-31   0.203000   11.145000    11.914663 1
2022-04-01   0.201063   10.281250    11.914663 1
2022-04-02   0.196372   10.917361    11.914663 1
2022-04-03   0.192194   10.894792    11.914663 1
2022-04-04   0.187135   11.161806    11.914663 1
               ...         ...          ...
2022-10-20   0.272309   14.650694    10.826096 2
2022-10-21   0.268503   14.418056    10.826096 2
2022-10-22   0.267260   13.947569    10.826096 2
2022-10-23   0.268302   13.447569    10.826096 2
2022-10-24   0.267096   13.122436    10.826096 2
```

Where mean_wcm3 is the daily soil moisture, mean_stemp is the daily soil temp, yield_Mg_ha is the yield at harvest and sample_id is the unique sample.